# Why my react date picker doesn't pop over when is displayed from a <Link>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-datepicker

I have the following React component:

```
import React from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import moment from 'moment'

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'

class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        //properties...
        myDate : moment()
      }
      this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    handleDateChange(date) {
      this.setState({
        myDate : date
      })
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      // implementation...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
                /* more components here... */
                <DatePicker 
                    dateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY' maxDate={ moment() } 
                    fixedHeight peekNextMonth showMonthDropdown showYearDropdown dropdownMode='select'
                    selected={ this.state.myDate } onChange={ this.handleDateChange }
                    />
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default MyForm
```

This component is shown under a Link used by react router. Here in my App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
              <Link to="/myForm">My Form</Link>
              <Route path="/myForm" component={MyForm} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    }
}
```

When I access to `http://localhost:3000/myForm`, the datepicker component is shown as a textbox, no animation, no date picker to display, nothing.

Then, I tried to just use the `<DatePicker>` inside App.js and worked like in the examples:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        dateField : moment()
      }
      this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleDateChange(date) {
      this.setState({
        dateField: date
      })
    }
    render() {
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
              <Link to="/myForm">My Form</Link>
              <Route path="/myForm" component={MyForm} />
            </div>
            <DatePicker 
                dateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY' maxDate={ moment() } 
                fixedHeight peekNextMonth showMonthDropdown showYearDropdown dropdownMode='select'
                selected={ this.state.dateField } onChange={ this.handleDateChange }
                />
        </Router>
    }
}
```

Now, I see both components at `http://localhost:3000/myForm`, the difference is that the picker in `MyForm` still can't pop over but the one in `App` does it.

Pictures to show these results.

Here: the date picker doesn't pop over. It's inside `MyForm` component:
[image]

Now using the date picker I added in App.js:

[image]

Comment: Are you making sure to import your `DatePicker` component in `MyForm`?

Comment: It is. Look at the `import` sentences in `MyForm`

Comment: Oops, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Do you have any output on the console? when clicking on the datepicker?

Comment: @JoseAPL I don't have any output. I've checked enabling all messages, but no warning nor error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

In `MyForm`, change `selected={this.state.fechaNacimento}` to `selected={this.state.myDate}`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake when adapting the code in form of question. I fixed that. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Hmm not entirely sure. Try checking the console in your browser to see if any errors are being logged.

Comment: Nothing is being logged as I've replied to Jose in the question.